# How to filter Outlook email using JavaMail API with IMAP

Tags: jakarta-mail

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
today.setTime(new Date());
Calendar prevTime = Calendar.getInstance();
prevTime.setTime(new Date());
prevTime.add(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(emailProps.getProperty("MINS_DIFF")) * -1 );;
ReceivedDateTerm minDateTerm = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GE, new Date(prevTime.getTimeInMillis()));
ReceivedDateTerm maxDateTerm = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.LE, new Date(today.getTimeInMillis()));
SearchTerm term = null;
term = new AndTerm(minDateTerm,maxDateTerm);
logger.debug("Filtering the date bw "+ new Date(prevTime.getTimeInMillis()).toString() + " and " +new Date(today.getTimeInMillis()).toString());
Message messages[] = folder.search(term);
```

Above is my code snippet, I have applied `searchterm` between 2 time but still the filter is not working, it's returning the whole day emails. For example for 26th dec there are 10 emails in my search folder, in that only 2 email received at my time period what I mentioned in the code. Here this `searchterm` returns me all the 10 emails.

Answer (score 0):

The IMAP protocol only allows searching based on day, not time.

You can use Folder.search to narrow the list to messages on the days you're interested in, and then apply the SearchTerm.match method to each message in the list, which will perform the match test on the client instead of asking the server to do it, and will thus be able to do a precise time match.

Comment: Thanks Bill, am doing like that only. Wanna know is there a way to overcome some other scenarios. Thanks once again :)

Comment: What other scenarios are you trying to overcome?